# PHP4 - Parse ini

Tags: php, parsing, ini

I'm doing this on an old NAS drive which has php embeded and is running PHP4.

parse_ini_file is supported, but I can't create an array of values within the returned results.

The following works :

```
[first_section]
one = 1
five = 5
animal = BIRD

[second_section]
path = "/usr/local/bin"
URL = "http://www.example.com/~username"

[third_section]
phpversion[] = "5.0"
phpversion[] = "5.1"
phpversion[] = "5.2"
phpversion[] = "5.3"

// Parse with sections
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini", true);
print_r($ini_array);
```

but the third section just returns :

```
[third_section] => Array
        (
            [phpversion[]] => 5.3
        )
```

Not all of the values.

Am I doing this wrong or is it due to PHP 4 ?

Any alternative methods ?

Comment: Usual implementations of ini asume that a repeated entry replaces the old one. You may consider using a special parser - although it seems easier to me to just use some notation to set the array, for example: `phpversion = ["5.0", "5.1", "5.2", "5.3"]` you will get that line from the parser, and then you can process it futher as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The example I posted is a php.net example, so I assumed it was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is due to PHP4. See http://3v4l.org/DMEud

The output starting from PHP 5 will give the third section as shown in the manual, while previous version will show the behavior you encounter.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this.  Are you aware of any solution that will produce the same results ?

Comment: @Rocket I am not aware of any userland libraries. You will likely have to write a parser yourself if you cannot change the keys to be unique.